# How to conform a given string to conform to regex

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way of taking a given string and passing it through a regex to get a new formatting?

I have two strings, `a="PRO999"` and `b="JHE986"` and the regex expression `\D{3}_\d{3}`. I want to be able to pass these strings and get `PRO_999` and `JHE_986`.

I could do this manually, but I know there will be times when I need the string to remain together and times when I need to apply the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `re.sub` here with capture groups:

```
a = "PRO999"
out = re.sub(r"(\D{3})(\d{3})", r"\1_\2", a)
```

### Demo

The default behavior of `re.sub` is to replace all occurrences.  So if `a` had more than one match, they would all be replaced.

Note: If you only want to match your pattern as a standalone word, then you may add word boundaries to the above pattern:

```
\b(\D{3})(\d{3})\b
```